# Why doesn't the div get height attribute from its' parent?

Tags: html, css, height

I gave the #header 82px height in CSS, but even though the #logo is its child, it doesn't get the 82px height. Should I just give #logo 82px height in CSS too?

Code: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF35n.png) & [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwX6N.png)
And also, I guess there's something wrong with HTML. I use Sublime Text and although all the other divs look colorful, the #header at line 10 looks pale. What's wrong with him?

Comment: Why did you post images of the code instead of just posting the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format code and things on this site.

Comment: I actually tried to give a jsfiddle link, then it asked me to use it with code, I tried to paste my code in code tag but the codes seemed ugly and long, so... I'm a little newbie here, sorry if it's disturbing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, an element's height is not inherited, it is automatic. That means the height will be automatically determined based on the content inside it.

You *can* explicitly set the child's height to inherit (`height: inherit`) and it will inherit whatever height you specify on the parent as well. See [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cCHDR/).

Comment: In comparison, block level elements, like div, fill the width of their container unless otherwise specified. Line level elements, like span, only fill the width of their content unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

unless you give a child div a height, it will wrap it's content. If you want to have the same height as the parent, set the child's height to `height:100%`